# Entity Framework EDMX Modifications Are Deleted

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm following the directions here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/0ce70e04-0ba0-4819-8898-87243203adb9/

to support mapping to a view that uses a CROSS APPLY UDF in it (basically EF can't determine the PK so it comments it out when I try to add it to my model).

After following the directions in the link, I'm able to successfully map to the view and query against it....but as soon as I try to U`pdate Model from Database` to pick up new changes to the schema, it wipes out the modifications I made per the instructions in the link (and I see in the wizard screen that it's says it wants to delete these entities).

Please tell me it's not supposed to work this way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy workaround is separate EDMX for all manually defined entities. Update from database always deletes SSDL part of EDMX (where the view is defined).

Edit:

Another approach is to modify your view code to include non-nullable (should be unique or you can expect another problems) column - it should be automatically inferred as a key. The uniqueness of the key is highly recommended anyway.

Comment: Thanks...How would I be able to add associations to these views if they're defined in a separate edmx?

Comment: You will not be able to do that.

Comment: Ok, how can I modify the view in this way?

Comment: The view is the result of a UDF

Comment: Normally EF infers the key as collection of all non-nullable, non-computed, non-binary columns.

Comment: Got it working by joining on a pk column returned by the udf. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The built-in "update model from database" wizard in Visual Studio does exactly that; it replaces the entire SSDL portion of the model, overwriting any customizations you have made.

There are third-party tools that allows you to do selective updates to the model, preserving customizations you may have done to other parts of the model and allowing you to select which changes you want to propagate across the layers. My company makes an add-in for Visual Studio that adds that capability (and a bunch of other useful features) to the EF4 designer. Here is an intro video showing off some of the basic sync capabilities: http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-model-comparer-for-entity.html